Flask SQLAlchemy config.from_object and init_app() give bind error
Found a working answer but not an explanation for why loading the full config before init_db causes a problem. See bottom.
I am adding the SQLAlchemy component to my code. App is configuring from an object. The object hasn't changed. The logging.debug output shows a valid app.config. But I'm getting an error when init_app(app) is run. It says it's a string obj?
# error msg
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 278, in __init__
    self.init_app(app)
  File "...\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 339, in init_app
    for key, value in config_binds.items():
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

# config.py
...
class AppConfig(FlaskConfig):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = FlaskConfig.DBPATH
    SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = FlaskConfig.SERVERNAME
    DEFAULT_PARSERS = [
        'flask.ext.api.parsers.JSONParser',
        'flask.ext.api.parsers.URLEncodedParser',
        'flask.ext.api.parsers.FormParser',
        'flask.ext.api.parsers.MultiPartParser'
        ]

    def __repr__(self):
        return (
        f"""
        {self.DRIVEDIR = }
        {self.SERVERNAME = }
        {self.SRCPATH = }
        {self.DBPATH = }
        """)

# app.py
# Update: Adding the import `from flask import Flask, config` didn't make a difference.*


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(AppConfig)
logging.debug(f"{app.config = }")

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.init_app(app)
# ma = Marshmallow(app)
# api = Api(app)

# logging output
Manually edited for this post. The original values for WindowsPaths and secret key work correctly.
app.config = <Config {'DEBUG': False, 'TESTING': False, 'PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS': None, 'SECRET_KEY': '******', 'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=31), 'USE_X_SENDFILE': False, 'SERVER_NAME': None, 'APPLICATION_ROOT': '/', 'SESSION_COOKIE_NAME': 
'session', 'SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_PATH': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY': True, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE': False, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE': None, 'SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST': True, 'MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH': None, 'SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT': None, 'TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS': None, 'TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS': False, 'EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING': False, 'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME': 'http', 'TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD': None, 'MAX_COOKIE_SIZE': 4093, 'APPHOST': '127.0.0.1', 'ASSETSPATH': WindowsPath('./archive_tool/assets'), 'CSRF_ENABLED': True, 'DBPATH': WindowsPath('./archive_tool/bookshelf.db'), 'DBURI': 'sqlite:///archive_tool\\bookshelf.db', 'DOWNLOADBASE': WindowsPath('./BookshelfTool_Output/HTMLDownloads'), 'HOSTPORT': 5000, 'PROCESSEDBASE': WindowsPath('./BookshelfTool_Output/ProcessedArchive'), 'PROJECTPATH': WindowsPath('.'), 'SERVERNAME': '127.0.0.1:5000', 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS': '127.0.0.1:5000', 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': WindowsPath('./archive_tool/bookshelf.db'), 'SQLALCHEMY_ECHO': True, 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS': False, 'SRCPATH': WindowsPath('./archive_tool'), 'UTILSPATH': WindowsPath('./archive_tool/utils')}>

Working solution: ORDER MATTERS
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from archive_tool import AppConfig

# 1. First, make an empty SQLAlchemy instance with `DeclarativeBase`
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
  pass

db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)

# 2. Make the Flask instance
app = Flask(__name__)
# 3. Assign ONLY the value for  `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']`
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = AppConfig.DBURI

# 4. Assign the Flask instance to the SQLAlchemy instance: run SQLAlchemy `init_db()` with the Flask instance
db.init_app(app)

# 5. Lastly, added the full config assignment to the Flask app
app.config.from_object(AppConfig)

